USB microscope and Cheese
Running Ubuntu 22.04. I have an Aveo Technology Corp. USB2.0 UVC PC Camera, a USB microscope, which shows up in Cheese. However, when attempting to take a picture, it always gives me a "There was an error playing video from the webcam" error. When attempting to capture video, Cheese crashes. This is clearly a uvc device so I'm not sure what's wrong or how to troubleshoot. I did notice however that the camera shows no picture upon opening Cheese, only after I go to preferences and change something like the resolution. Then a stream shows up and I can put the resolution back to what it was, but again, can't save photos.
There was originally a program to open the camera that came on a CD for I think Windows, but my computer today runs Ubuntu and has no CD drive.
Any help would be appreciated.
